# How to Rollback database in Microservice if RabbitMQ down permanently?

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, saga

I am trying to communicate between four services in Microservice. Every service has serperate Database. I am using saga pattern.
My question is, if RabbitMQ goes down or crash or no way to come back, how would I rollback or revert database without help of message Queue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using SAGA pattern to maintain consistency in your microservice application. Main component for this pattern is the Orchestrator which coordinates your microservice and I'm assuming that in your application you are using rabitmq for message passing.
One way is to store your message in the local database of your microservice if you're not able to send a message to the queue you can add a scheduler that will try to send the message to the queue after some interval.
The second way can be to use rabitmq in cluster mode this will prevent a Single Point of failure for your application.

Comment: Hi Ranja,n Thanks for your answer, basically i have tested on kubernetes cluster and everything working fine but the scenario i am working on, if rabbitMQ goes down and does not replicate, is there a way to revert all other database. (might sound unrealistic scenario but looking for a way if poosible). ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to keep your message publishing in scope of your local transaction so lets say your first service did some change in its local database before committing the transaction you make sure that your message has been ack by rabbitmq if rabbitmq ack your service message commit your transaction if rabbitmq is down rollback your transaction.